# Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions, faq-proposed

Are there some particular items I should be including in my **SQL** questions that would help others better understand the problem and attract more useful answers?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

**Canonical link** (of this post for reference):

`https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055`

`[Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)`

Comment: Also see http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/

Answer (score 106):

## Figure Out What is Essential For Us - Keep it Brief and Relevant

If you're asking *why* something in SQL works the way it does, keep in mind that SQL is *declarative,* not *procedural.* SQL describes *what* you want, not *how to get it.* (By contrast, most programming languages are procedural.) The various table servers contain elaborate query planners to work out the best way to get what you want. Please consider reading [this about the basic technology](http://coding-geek.com/how-databases-work/), and [this about indexing](https://use-the-index-luke.com/).

Ask yourself this question: If I have no idea about my system/setup/situation what is a simple way to describe it?

Don't waste our time on loads of code or paragraphs of information when it is not directly related to the question at hand. Keep it brief, to the point, detailed, and include the specific snippet of code related. If we need more information, we will let you know.

## Writing a Good Question - Keep it Structured / Ordered

Think of it this way. When you write your question you are writing an essay. There are key pieces of information that we need before we can help you and those would be the following points.

### 1. Problem Statement - What problem are you stuck with?

```
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|          BAD          |                      GOOD                           |
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|  "it errors"          |  "It errors with the message (your error message)"  |
|  "it's not working"   |  "I'm stuck on the next part of this query"         |
|  "what happened"      |  "how do I do (whatever you need to do)"            |
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

The `BAD` examples aren't problem statements. They give the community no help or guidance on what the error is.
The `GOOD` examples are good ways to tell the community if you are running into an error or can't wrap your mind around the next step in your query. 
It's hard for us to look at a question that doesn't detail these things out, and understand what you want unless you provide some detail yourself!  More specific problem statements will help attract better answers and even upvotes.

### 2. Give the Background - Relevant Data? Attempts?

#### A. The first thing you should do is lay out some data for the community to visually see what you are working with.

This data should be minimized and just enough to show what you are working with. Generally 5-15 rows is enough data for question readers to get a good feel for the data.

For example:

```
table : people
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|    id |    name   |    status |        phone      |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|    1  |    John   |        1  |    214-444-1234   |
|    2  |    Mary   |        0  |    555-111-1234   |
|    3  |    Jeff   |        0  |    214-222-1234   |
|    4  |    Bill   |        1  |    817-333-1234   |
|    5  |    Bob    |        1  |    214-555-1234   |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
```

#### B. After showing what the data is like, you should also show what attempts you have made.

```
My Attempt:
I have written the query up to this point, but am stuck on what to do next

    SELECT id, name, status, phone
    FROM people
    WHERE status = 1;

The issue I'm having is I need to filter not only by a status of 1 but
also by the phone number starting with 214
```

This tells us not only what you want, but what you have tried, and you will get an answer a LOT faster.

#### C. Consider providing an SQL Fiddle or DB Fiddle

Here would be mine for the examples in this answer [SQL fiddle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) and in [DB Fiddle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks?newreg=4c3b0dfc1bc84d048059fd51995be403).
It is very easy to use: put your [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) and [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements (the create, insert, update, alter... etc. statements) on the left and your query statements (the select, set... etc statements) on the right.

By providing a SQL fiddle, you allow people to execute queries to test and not only give you a faster answer, but also a more accurate answer, as it will already be tested.

Keep in mind that providing an SQL Fiddle is no substitute for providing the actual table structure and other details in your problem.  You must still include those details (preferably as text) in your question.  The SQL Fiddle enhances your question, but it is not sufficient by itself.

Note: SQLFiddle or DBFiddle may not work for some databases. As alternatives, you can try to use [Rextester.com](http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler) or [dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/) and choose the database.

### 3. Show Your Expected Outcome

This is a *MUST* and is often overlooked. You need to show what you want to do with the data in case someone doesn't understand your question or your problem statement. This way they can see how you want the data manipulated, and do it for you!

For Example:

```
I want my final results to look like this:
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|    id |    name   |    status |        phone      |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|    1  |    John   |        1  |    214-444-1234   |
|    5  |    Bob    |        1  |    214-555-1234   |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
```

### 4. If you're asking about query performance

If you're asking "Why is my query slow?" or something like that, you need to do a little extra homework to get good answers from Stack Overflow.

Put the [query-performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-performance) tag on your question.

Please figure out approximately how many rows you expect in your result set, and approximately how many rows are in each table involved with the query. Mention those numbers in your question. Please mention how long you hope your query needs to take, and how long it's taking. (That is, tell us what you mean by *slow*).

Don't try to simplify your question by replacing your actual `SELECT` column lists with `*`.  Using `*` in `SELECT` clauses is **harmful** to query performance compared to specifying the list of columns you need.

In your question please show the `EXPLAIN PLAN` output (it's just `EXPLAIN` in some table server makes and models) for your query. Also please show the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` for each table involved in your query. Make sure your question shows **all indexes** in **all relevant tables**.  When you're asking a performance question, please don't oversimplify your question by omitting indexes or columns you think might be irrelevant.  The strangest things can be relevant to performance!

Please be aware that query performance optimization can be an inexact science. This is a good reference.  http://use-the-index-luke.com/

### 5. Some Additional Suggestions

Another thing you can do to improve your questions is to try and add the actual DDL / DML statements to your question.

You can put the data directly in your question or if its a lot of information to show in a question you can [Create a Gist](https://gist.github.com/) to share code snippets

```
CREATE TABLE people(
  id int,
  name varchar(55),
  status int,
  phone varchar(55)
);

INSERT INTO people VALUES
(1, 'John', 1, '214-444-1234'),
(2, 'Mary', 0, '555-111-1234'),
(3, 'Jeff', 0, '214-222-1234'),
(4, 'Bill', 1, '817-333-1234'),
(5, 'Bob' , 1, '214-555-1234');
```

You can also post the `EXPLAIN` execution plan for the table. I prefer `EXPLAIN (query) \g` as it puts it in rows instead of columns which is easier to read.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT id, name, status, phone
FROM people
WHERE status = 1;
+-------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
|    ID |    SELECT_TYPE|    TABLE  |    TYPE   |    POSSIBLE_KEYS  |    KEY    |    KEY_LEN    |    REF    |    ROWS   |        EXTRA  |
+-------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
|    1  |    SIMPLE     |    people |    ALL    |    (null)         |    (null) |    (null)     | (null)    |    5      |   Using where |
+-------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
```

These are *VERY* helpful for when you want help increasing the *performance* / speed of a query or want help with *indexing*

## Formatting Your Post - Gotta Make it Pretty!

For help with formatting code using Stack Overflow's methods read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks?newreg=4c3b0dfc1bc84d048059fd51995be403) or visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) 
For help with formatting your sql queries you can use an SQL formatter like [this SQL formatter](http://sqlformat.org/) 
For help with formatting the output just copy the output into this [table builder](http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)

## One Last Note

*DO NOT* take a working solution/answer and [*forget to Accept it*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) when the answer solves your issue! There's nothing more annoying when you post a perfectly good and correct answer and there is no activity on the question again.  Don't forget to upvote helpful answers and downvote unhelpful ones.

Comment: not sure how this is considered too broad.. this is specific to all server side queries.

Comment: The [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/info) would be a good place for a condensed form of this answer.

Comment: @JoshCaswell but why not just remove MySQL from the title.. add a MySQL header in this answer to be for all server side server queries(sql), and then put up two more answers.. one for server side programming languages, and one for front end where you include a jsfiddle for front end.. etc? could even close it afterwards to prevent other answers

Comment: I agree with @Josh that this would be good information to add to the tag wiki, although I don't agree with the close votes on the question (at least, not when the scope was limited to MySQL).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I changed it to be more generic so that we could put in three answers for the three main types of areas for programming (from the downvotes and comments saying it needed to be more generic)... if this is added to the tag wiki then you would need to add it to each tag.. and that is tedious.. i still think three answers focusing generally on those three areas would be a great resource for others. but maybe i'm mistaken

Comment: @John Sorry, I wasn't clear in my last comment. I agree that this is great information to have, and I think it belongs on meta (hence my disagreement with the close votes). I think it would *also* be useful to add in a reduced form to *some* tag wikis. However, I think having three long answers to this question would require a lot of scrolling, so personally I think three separate questions would be better. But that's just me.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot which is why I initially put it up as MySQL... sigh everyone is so critical these days. I purposefully didn't put it on stack overflow but meta because thats where things like this belong, even though I'm not getting reputation from it. its solely for the benefit of others. I think I'm going to change it back to just sql and this question should be locked to prevent other answers.. then it would be awesome to get two more questions for the other two :)

Comment: This kind of thing should be in the Tag Wiki, not here on Meta.

Comment: This looks more like some sort of blog post than an actual question/answer

Comment: @RobertHarvey but putting it in the tag wiki would be really tedious... should there be a condensed version of this answer in every tag related to SQL? what about other programming languages.. seems like its better to put it in one place

Comment: @SamIam not so sure about that, its about how to ask a Stack Overflow question, which is why I figured it should be in Meta Stack Overflow....

Comment: @RobertHarvey Given that the SO Academy proposal was closed and was intended for this sort of stuff, I'd rather it be here where it will actually be seen.

Comment: I don't have a problem with it being here in principle, but most of what you're describing here is already adequately covered by the "insufficient information" close reason.  *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)*

Comment: @RobertHarvey I agree that some of my post has similar contents as the help page has... but it doesn't have a lot of the specifics that helps users get over that hurtle of asking a bad question. giving examples of good and bad ways to do something I think is a great way to help others improve their questions.

Comment: I particularly like the last bit regarding acceptances - thanks!

Comment: You should provide some info on how you formatted your tables and code.

Comment: @Will I don't think thats needed... theres a lot of helps already out there on how to do that and it would be redundant to post that plus the post is already a decent length.. I added a line at the bottom with two links for formatting tricks/tips incase someone comes here and doesn't know how to.

Comment: If somebody is reading this then they are clueless, and links to resources for prettifying inputs and sql would be **incredibly** helpful.  A quick search didn't reveal any decent sources for these to me.  Hell, formatting issues is the most common issue among bad questions; why specifically leave information about that out of your answer?  Stop boggling with my mind.

Comment: @Will are you talking about formatting a sql query like with indents? or formatting with the tools SO provides? everyone has a different preference on how to read a sql query with indentation and such,.. I can add my preference but it'll not what some people prefer.

Comment: Not SO tools, that's already documented.  Pretty-printing SQL resources and resources for creating ascii tables would be very useful for your hypothetical audience, I would believe.

Comment: @Will ah ok check out my edit.. I misunderstood what you were asking originally... my bad.

Comment: My only comment is that the question should also strive to be brief'ish.  One could follow your guidelines and write a question spanning many pages -- and it would never get answered.  And, you should highlight SQL Fiddle a bit more.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you for your comments! if you want to look at the edits I made I tried to incorporate your suggestions

Comment: John, you've put in a lot of time and effort into this and think it's a valuable Q&A for the community. If I come up with anything else, I will let you know. Great job. +1 on both counts.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks! (too bad you don't get rep for it on meta lol) feel free to edit it if you do think of something and feel free to link to it whenever you see a question that needs some help :)

Comment: You're welcome John. Yeah, well maybe Stack will change that later on lol - I will edit, and do correct me should I get anything wrong or needs improvement on. I will add your Q&A to my profile ;) cheers

Comment: Actually, I think adding the relevant tables DDL as well as DML for sample data is better and more important then creating a fiddle. The reason for this is that SqlFiddle.com is limited to a very small subset of versions, and also suffers from a lot of downtime. By adding the DDL+DML to the question directly you are increasing your chances of getting the correct answer faster even if sql fiddle is down.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I agree that its very useful to have the DDL and DML, I have seen people use sqlfiddle just to show the DML and DDL (not even for executing queries) because the question would be too long and unmanagable, which is why I still think sqlfiddle is a great tool

Comment: @john sure it's a greate tool, I use it all the time. But except in cases like you described, I think it's no replacment for adding the ddl+dml. I think the best option is to have both ddl+dml in the question and also a fiddle.

Comment: @ZoharPeled only problem with that is I hate coming to a question and I have to keep scrolling because there are like 10 tables being used and there is tons of stuff to show for that. i'll add to my answer an option to create a gist to show the DML and DDL since it is important to have that

Comment: @ZoharPeled also I already had a section more towards the end that says you can add the DML and DDL statements to your question, so I just edited that part and added a "create a gist" if its too much

Comment: SQL Fiddle might be very useful, but surely it shouldn't be stressed as much as a requirement.  I'm not a fan of the __IMPORTANT__.  But I'll leave this comment instead of an edit for some feedback first.

Comment: @ryanyuyu other people dont agree... read previous comments

Comment: @JohnRuddell And I only see one other user's comment besides yours that really want to stress the fiddle.  I think it's a fine idea, I just don't think it needs to be that stressed.  Let me just say that I'm getting bold-fatigued from reading this.

Comment: haha ok point taken, feel free to edit it if you think that'll improve the post. its for the community

Comment: @JohnRuddell New edit.  I've muted some of the less important parts of the post.  Also, a warning to not rely _entirely_ on SQL fiddle.

Comment: Lots of useful info and links!

Comment: Some guidance on formatting (e.g. indentation) and capitalisation of SQL would be nice.

Comment: ad 5) CTE with test data (i.e. `with t as (values (...),(...),...)`) should be IMHO explicitly mentioned as alternative to `create table + insert into` tandem. At least where the question is matter of logic rather than performance. Sometimes I cannot (or am too lazy to do it) build schema or start docker container, not speaking about manual rewriting. I observe many novice OPs don't know this construct and place plain text or csv into questions (or some fancy ascii-art borders or even screenshots in worst cases), so this could be helpful for them in the first place.

Comment: I second the CTE comment. This is a very handy alternative.

Comment: It would be very helpful to have a reference to this question from relevant tag wiki's, such as *sql*, *sqlite*, etc.