# Good examples of database questions providing some sample data in the question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

**Model the Desired Behavior**

I would like some excellent examples I can point users to when they ask questions that provide little or no sample data, making them nearly impossible to answer.

What are questions that you have asked, answered or seen that can be held up for novices as good examples?

Here are some I've come across:

- [How to Query Data From SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043162/how-to-query-data-from-sql-server) (my fav so far)
- [Oracle SQL Query Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480856/order-sql-query-data)
- [PHP Oracle Query Data Grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271426/php-oracle-query-data-grouping) (don't care for the image at top)

Perhaps add examples one per question so we can vote them up or down. I suggest we vote based primarily on the quality of the sample data in the question, but also on the quality of the sample data in the answers.

**Edit**: As a product of the this discussion, I have asked a different version of this question which is ms-access specific ([see here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299722/good-examples-of-ms-access-questions-providing-some-sample-data-in-the-question)).

Comment: You might be interested in this faq-proposed question:  [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question).  I'm not too keen on "collecting" a bunch of good sql questions, but that might be a good place to house them.  Perhaps as another community wiki answer showing a list of good examples.

Comment: I ran this search on SO `[sql] is:question score:1... data` which looks for questions tagged with SQL, have a positive score and have the word data in them.  Tweak to your needs.  Found a few decent ones in there after some casual clicking.

Comment: For me are the best ones those including (except table visualization) also SQL fiddle.

Comment: I'm surprised that 2 or the 3 "examples of great questions" you provided had only 1 upvote (until I voted).  Do people not upvote questions that are well written? I thought that was the point.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The examples you've shared are okay, but perhaps we should aim for more. I think **an actual repro with code is preferred** to a table-formatted-code block. E.g. I prefer this:

> I've got a question about XYZ, because I want to do ABC. Suppose the following scenario:
>
> ```sql
> CREATE TABLE Employee (Id INT, BossId INT, Name NVARCHAR(50));
>
> INSERT INTO Employee (Id, BossId, Name) 
> VALUES
>     (1, NULL, 'Boss Pancone'),
>     (2, 1, 'Capioregime Luciano'),
>     (3, 1, 'Capioregime Bruno'),
>     (4, 2, 'Johnny'),
>     (5, 2, 'Luca'),
>     (6, 2, 'Luciano jr.'),
>     (7, 3, 'Marco'),
>     (8, 3, 'Mario'),
>     (9, 3, 'Giacomo');
> ```
>
> With this scenario I'm trying to do ABC in the following manner...

Over this:

> I've got a question about XYZ, because I want to do ABC. Suppose the following scenario:
>
> ```
> Id    BossId    Name
> ----  --------  -------------------
> 1     NULL      Boss Pancone
> 2     1         Capioregime Luciano
> 3     1         Capioregime Bruno
> 4     2         Johnny
> 5     2         Luca
> 6     2         Luciano jr.
> 7     3         Marco
> 8     3         Mario
> 9     3         Giacomo
> ```
>
> With this scenario I'm trying to do ABC in the following manner...

*The question itself should always contain all code*, but a supporting link to [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) or similar is always nice (which in fact *requires* creating sample data with actual runnable code).

I don't think my questions that utilize this method are examplary enough to refer to, but nonetheless, if you're interested, you can see how I'd do this when [asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27637278/419956) or [when answering one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17571853/419956).

Comment: I've seen examples like that, which are great, but too much to ask from the majority of ms-access folks who are asking the questions. Most of the probably do not know sql.

Comment: @DonJewett: And, which may or may not be obvious to those who have not used Access much, there's no easy way to automatically get DDL like that from the GUI, or anywhere else for that matter: it has to be hand-written, basically always.

Comment: @DonJewett: it would be helpful if you could provide an example of a reasonable (even if poorly-presented) database-related question, in which the questioner can plausibly not know SQL, nor know how to use some SQL-aware tools, and yet could understand and use a good answer to that question. That would help us understand why we should not expect a database-related question to NOT contain content that can be directly copied and pasted, in order for an answerer to compose and test an answer.

Comment: And for the record, I agree 100% with Jeroen that providing data in a directly-pasteable format is strongly preferred, if not simply mandatory. It is unreasonable of any questioner to expect readers to do _any_ work that the questioner themselves could have done on behalf of the reader.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Here is the one that prompted my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31442353/correction-query?noredirect=1#comment50894142_31442353 and before it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31445045/ms-access-output-duplicate-rows-on-joined-tables/31449172 I don't know if I would say these are reasonable, but the users seem like novices. I doubt they have the skill to write a create table or insert.

Comment: @DonJewett: sorry, but I'm not getting it. Of those two questions: `...353` specifically states the author has _" created several queries"_. Now, maybe they aren't using SQL (the example appears to be some Access-specific language), but it seems whatever language they are using, an expression that would build the necessary table would be possible. `...045` includes some actual SQL, which presumably the author understands. I don't see why in either of those examples, one would be led to believe that the author is incapable of including copy/paste code to generate the necessary example data.

Comment: There's [~7k sql questions *with* also ms-access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+ms-access), and [~278k questions *without* ms-access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+-ms-access). My advice / answer was meant for the general case. Whether ms-access is an exceptional case is a matter for another, more specific question IMO. I suggest, if it's important to someone, they'd ask a new, more specific version of this question (e.g. "*Good examples of **ms-access** questions providing some sample data in the question?*").

Comment: I also have to use a database that doesn't use a standard schema (there are others besides Access) but I still agree that this should be the specified example for any FAQ or General Example - particularly because creating a general case many times either gives the OP an answer without needing to post or actually gives the true problem (so it is not an X/Y Question). This is just a good debugging practice that we should promote when possible.

Comment: good points. I agree that this method is preferable, and access is a special case.

Comment: Well, I tried asking an ms-access specific version of this, but it has been put on hold. Am I just wasting my time on meta? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299722/good-examples-of-ms-access-questions-providing-some-sample-data-in-the-question

Comment: I've answered a few Oracle SQL question with data examples as in @Don's initial question. For Micky Mouse data where there is no executable sample I added `WITH` clause(s) to `UNION ALL` some sample data together. It's very useful for checking my answer in my dev environment (Toad). I does make the answer less readable but helps easily test my and future answers. Should I keep doing it, stop it, add it to the question edit or stop and rework it in SqlFiddle (unlikely)?