# Should a self-answered canonical question be posted on Meta Stack Overflow instead of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, self-answer, community-wiki

I spend a lot of time in the [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) tag and see a lot of questions that don't provide the basics, including: schema, dummy data and desired output.

I decided to [self-answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46491717/sharing-a-sql-server-issue-with-someone-that-cant-access-my-database) with a community wiki answer, that I could use as a pointer for users that may not be aware of how they could help themselves.

It was suggested in comments that the Q&A should have been placed on meta, so I'm here to verify if what I've done is OK.

Comment: The question certainly isn't appropriate on meta, as it's not asking a question *about Stack Overflow as a site*.  It doesn't really look like an appropriate question for main either though.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Sure, the question is whether it's on topic on SO to ask how to share a problem with a colleague (I lean towards no, but I'm not entirely sure of that).  The post being self-answered is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: Note that you could perhaps *rewrite* the question into one that would be on topic on meta.  If, instead of asking how to pose a problem to a colleague, you simply asked how to properly construct enough information on how to ask a query related question on SO, it might be on topic here.  Of course, there are lots of meta questions on how to create an MCVE, so be sure that it's not already duplicated on meta (you may be better off posting an answer to an existing meta question, if you can find a suitable one).

Comment: I agree with Servy, this doesn't look like a suitable Q&A for either the main site or meta. It is more like a blog post, similar to what Jon Skeet wrote: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/. You could use your own blog as well or maybe ask John if he can host your Q&A as one of his blog posts?

Comment: As usual - showing effort (i.e. https://www.bing.com/search?q=%2Bmcve%20sql) is required even for self-answered questions... If you'd tried you find plenty questions with comments about providing "SQL MCVE" (i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42486431/how-to-pivot-temp-table-in-sql) which point to much better existing https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056

Comment: Should I vote to delete the post then? As the meta link @AlexeiLevenkov provided is much more detailed, I just hadn't seen it before. It has an up voted answer now.

Comment: @Tanner Sadly you can't delete it anymore as there's an upvoted answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Meta Stack Overflow is for questions **about** Stack Overflow, so no, it is absolutely not the right place for it, as it is written now.

In general, the concept of asking and self answering a common question is done frequently on Stack Overflow.  You do not need to make the answer community wiki either.  If you write your own answer that is yours alone and not an aggregate of of the contributions of multiple users, you should be entitled to earn rep from the post.  Community Wiki is for answers that include contributions from multiple users, or at a minimum a single user that is not yourself.

The key point however is the question must be on-topic for Stack Overflow.  That includes meeting the question quality expectations.  The question must be clear and not "too broad", and be on-topic per the scope in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  If an MCVE is needed, make sure it is included.  The question must be completely answerable by anyone, not just OP. And don't forget to check for duplicates too.  No sense asking a new question when an existing one covers the topic already.

Comment: _"not "too broad""_ - why? Don't think it's a point for canonical question with answer.

Comment: Canonical Q&As do still have to have a limit to how much ground they should cover, even if that limit is a bit more than the average question.

Answer (score 9):

Canonical question should be posted on the site where they are on-topic. In your case that is Stack Overflow.

Only that guarantees that the right people find it, vote on it, edit it and use it as a duplicate target.

Most important is that you still have to ask a GOOD Question and write an acceptable answer. Don't confuse the Q/A pair for your personal blog space.

Although you're free to create a canonical and self-answer, the more successful examples of such questions were the work of a community effort. There are a few process described on meta how to reach that point. for example in [Process for nominating and promoting canonical questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276010/process-for-nominating-and-promoting-canonical-questions) and in an answer of mine [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252046/578411).

On the specific example question: please make sure it doesn't become a spam magnet for a myriad of (web)tools.