# Was this comment about question formatting meaningful?

Tags: discussion, questions, comments

My question is born from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52833279/how-to-select-first-table-data-based-on-another-table-based-on-one-column-succes/52833364#comment92583068_52833279) thread:

It regards the OP comment stating:

> Sample data is best served as DDL + DML. Please edit your question to
>   include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more
>   details, read this(link: https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql).

From my knowledge, the content of this comment stands well: The OP had posted *images* of tables, which is not a good practice for all the reasons most of us know.

However, by the time this comment was posted, there were already 3 correct answers, one of which had a comment from OP that "it worked".

My question is: was it still meaningful to have that comment posted?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Yes, it is.

The presence of (working) answers is by no means a good reason to stop improving a question, or to stop helping OP improve a question. And as you can see, the question has been adjusted to include this content.

Both questions and answers are intended to be of use to future readers.

Do note the [tips for SQL questions on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/7296893) are a bit different than those on Meta DBA, imo we should refer to the MSO one, and if that's inferior to the Meta DBA one, improve it.

Answer (score 21):

> My question is: was it still meaningful to have that comment posted?

Yes. OP may have been helped, but Stack Overflow aims for more: We also want future visitors to be helped. Future visitors do not have inside information on the exact issue, including crucial missing details, like OP does. They might have the same issue but might be unable to find the solved question because it lacks a proper definition.

Improving a question to enable more people to benefit from its content is always worth doing on this site.