# Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?

Tags: discussion, tags, faq-proposed

I have a question about a SQL query, so I put a [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) tag on it.

In the comments, people are telling me to "tag my RDBMS".

Why should I do that since I already tagged the programming language?

(*This topic is intended to serve as a FAQ*.)

Comment: Please don't downvote questions asked in good faith; it's unhelpful. It pushes the question off of the front page (and only findable using arcane magic) and it discourages meta participation by newcomers to meta. Voting is only used to signal disagreement for feature requests; otherwise voting works the same way it does on every other SE site. On meta: "On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself." https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: If anything, this belongs to the tag wiki, not as a meta faq, IMO.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I don't see the relevance of your comment here. Clearly people aren't downvoting this to signal "disagreement". That wouldn't even *mean* anything in this context.

Comment: @yivi This will provide a good link for users to provide which could be easier to use then a tag wiki which doesn't get read

Comment: @Joe, if it's about "providing a link", it's also possible to provide users with a [link to the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info)

Comment: @MarkAmery Downvoting means "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"  None of those apply; so I can only assume that people are voting according to the 'voting means disagreement on meta' trope.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker In your opinion none apply. It's clearly possible for somebody to think that this question is not useful (e.g. due to the answer being obvious, and there being no reason to treat SQL tags differently from any other kind of tagging and no clear reason why we need a question about this particular case). Whatever their motives and whether or not they're reasonable, they still can't possibly be "disagreement" because there's no position stated in the *question* for anyone to disagree with.

Comment: Conversely, @George, upvoting to counteract downvotes are also not voting the way it was meant to be used; I don't see a point in trying to suppress how people vote.  It's like herding cats; the best you can do is guide them in a rough direction, and trying to railroad them just means they scatter everywhere instead.

Comment: @fbueckert I vote according to the criteria in the hover: "this question shows research effort; it is useful and clear."

Comment: Arguably, votes could be used to express agreement or disagreement with designating this an official FAQ. But then again... this is yet another argument about votes and how should users be casting them.

Comment: Either way, this discussion doesn't belong here; it should be an entirely separate question.  We're distracting from the main point of this one.

Comment: @yivi No reason it can't be both; an FAQ question explaining in detail why it's a good idea to do this in detail could conceivably be a helpful resource to link askers to who argue about it, I suppose. But do we actually have a problem with people posting [sql] questions that don't specify their RDMS in the first place? It's not immediately obvious whether there's a real problem being solved here and thus whether writing all this serves any purpose, whether it goes here or in the [sql] tag wiki.

Comment: Is there a SQL chatroom where this FAQ proposal was discussed? E.g. whether it should happen, and/or whether it should be posted here or added to the tag wiki? Or whether it should have just been added to the existing SQL FAQ that's already a FAQ? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: Related feature request: [Help the helpless with how-to-ask tag tips](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274632)

Comment: What is RDBMS?.

Comment: @JL2210 Answered in the answer :).

Comment: Discussion about this FAQ proposal: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388842/1709587

Answer (score 47):

There are two things at work here.

1. What SQL is, and is not.
2. [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

***First, regarding "SQL"***:

'SQL' stands for **S**tructured **Q**uery **L**anguage, but it's not a programming language, like Python or C# or Java. Organizations such as [ANSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_National_Standards_Institute) and [ISO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Organization_for_Standardization) periodically publish guidelines regarding features that should be included in an implementation of SQL, but database vendors are free to use a much or as little of that guidance as they decide to use when they create their databases and related products.

Each vendor of a **D**ata**b**ase **M**anagement **S**ystem (**DBMS**), or, if it's a **R**elational database, **RDBMS**, is free to develop their own version of SQL, which we refer to as *dialects*. Most SQL functionality is available in most database systems, but the syntax from one to the other is often very different and is rarely "portable". Moving from one system to another almost invariably requires some translation work.

For you to get a good answer to your question, you'll want to tell the Stack Overflow community what dialect of SQL you're writing in. You do that by adding a tag to your question for the specific database that you're working with; for instance [postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql), [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle), [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server), [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access),[mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql),[db2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/db2),[hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hive),[teradata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/teradata), or [netezza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netezza).

Also, each vendor tends to add or remove features from one version of its product to the next. To be sure that the answers you get will run in your environment, it is often helpful to add an additional tag for the specific version of the database that you are using. For instance [oracle12c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle12c) or [sql-server-2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2019).

***Second, regarding tags:***

You're not just tagging for the community, you're also tagging for yourself.

The link in point two, above, will take you to the Stack Overflow page on **tagging**, and while it has some interesting information, at this time it doesn't really explain why tagging your question effectively is important to you, the one looking for a solution to your problem.

People who answer questions on Stack Overflow typically have a cluster of tags that they "watch". When they go looking for questions to answer, they use those tags to filter all 200 zillion questions on the site down to just the ones that they think they'll feel comfortable answering.

By using the right tags, you're taking an important step toward getting your question in front of the people who are *most likely to be able to help you answer it*.

With that said, after you do get an answer (or answers!) to your question, having the question tagged well will help search engines find the question for future developers who have a similar question, so you're also doing them a favor. But that's just icing on the cake.

Tag selfishly; you're on the site because you're looking for help, and the right tags will help you get it.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with this guidance; to people who aren't inside baseball, 'sql' and 'ansi-sql' might as well be synonymous.  We can add the tag 'ansi-sql' when they're asking a question implementing something according to ANSI SQL, but it's very useful to have implementation agnostic SQL answers available.

Comment: If there's a question that's actually DBMS agnostic, you're right, @GeorgeStocker, but there are literally dozens of questions a day posted with just a `sql` tag where the solution is, ultimately, dependent on the DBMS the OP is using. The request for clarification happens so often, that I wrote this up to give a linkable, more thorough explanation than will fit comfortably in a comment.

Comment: What to do if I only have a question about general SQL syntax? Should I tag it with just [sql]?

Comment: We found the [sql] tag so useless on dba.se [we burninated it](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3038)

Comment: I believe this would be better off as tag usage guidance below the SQL tag wiki. Except... it is already there https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info. Overall, tag wiki is a better place to use than meta, for these kind of tag-specific guidelines.

Comment: @weegee: yes, correct.

Comment: @weegee: if you have a question about general SQL syntax, it probably means you're trying to find common ground between various implementations (where you may or may not have specifically identified which implementations you're interested in).  There are very few parts of SQL that are truly DBMS-agnostic.  There's no "general SQL DBMS" that supports (only) "general SQL syntax" that I know of — they all have their own quirks.