# Discussion of the 'Why should I "tag my RDBMS"' FAQ proposal

Tags: discussion

[Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388759/1709587) proposes adding a question to the FAQ about why users should tag their RDBMS when asking SQL questions. At the time that I post this, it's controversial - sitting at +23 / -14.

I'm conscious of the fact that - in the current moderation environment on Meta, where comments may be deleted without reason - there's no stable medium for people to explain why they are downvoting it, nor for the asker or the upvoters to explain why they think the question would be useful to have in the FAQ. Thus, I am creating this discussion about it.

Should the post be added to the FAQ? Is it really something that askers fail to understand? Is it relevant to enough questions or enough users to merit being in the FAQ? Is the *answer* given there correct and useful?

Comment: Tangential meta-meta two cents: discussing the appropriateness of a [faq-proposed] in the [faq-proposed] itself is awkward regardless of the strictness of comment moderation, so I don't think the justification in the second paragraph is truly necessary. Discussions about the need for a [faq] are often held before it is posted; the only difference here is that you are doing it after it was posted, which seems entirely fine to me.

Comment: \*sigh\*  The ***only*** reason that this is even a discussion point is because [of the refusal to actually break it out into a separate discussion point](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/197298?m=47081895#47081895) to get the Help Center wording changed to represent current thinking.  The *insistence* of bringing this point up in spite of the fact that Meta has clearly *moved past* what is in the Help Center is starting to grate on my nerves.

Comment: @makoto you’re certainly encouraged to bring it up as a meta question. I believe it was discussed in either 2014 or 2016 and changes were declined; but that doesn’t mean you can’t talk about it. My response was *I’m* not up for raising a meta question about it because I don’t see it as a productive use of my time. The camps are entrenched and neither will change the other’s Mind, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker:  I might do that, but honestly - I kind of wish *you* would.  You keep bringing it up often enough and IMO it derails discussions and scatters information, kind of like what we've got going here and now.

Comment: What FAQ are you speaking of? This? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: @Lundin No, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388759/1709587 - the one I linked to. I hadn't realised there were two related [faq-proposed] questions about asking SQL questions.

Comment: Nobody probably realizes, which is why this stuff shouldn't be on meta to begin with, but on the main site in the form of tag wiki.

Answer (score 6):

Some observations and thoughts about that Q&A as it stands, not intended as a cohesive argument for a particular side:

- Failure by askers to tag their RDBMS seems to be a real thing. I've looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql?tab=Newest on a couple of occasions since the FAQ proposal was posted and there always seem to be a handful of posts lacking necessary information about the RDBMS being used amongst the latest 50 [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) questions asked.
- While the FAQ proposal focuses purely on tagging, it's not just failure to *tag* the RDBMS specifically that's a problem, but also failure to indicate it in any way whatsoever in the question.
- I've *not* seen any instance of an asker arguing or questioning the reason for being asked to tag their RDBMS.
- The FAQ proposal as currently written doesn't give any examples of differences between RDBMSes. That seems like a pity; there are some differences that can be easily understood by people with only basic SQL knowledge (like that SQL Server uses `TOP` while other SQL dialects use `LIMIT`), and I think including such examples would be one of the most useful ways to illustrate the point to SQL beginners.
- The un-caveated advice to tag your specific RDBMS *version* (like [sql-server-2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2019) in addition to [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server)) seems bad to me. When it comes to programming language tagging, our standard advice is to use version tags only if you know that the question you are asking is version-specific. Why should RDBMS tags be any different?
- It's a mere quibble, but I think the claim that *"Most SQL functionality is available in most database systems"* is misleading given that it comes right after mentioning the distinction between a DBMS and an RDBMS. I fear that to a reader unfamiliar with the terminology, it makes it sound like even non-relational databases mostly use SQL.

Comment: "Most basic SQL functionality standardized in the last century is available in most database systems, but with wildly different implementation details, behaviour and even possibly completely distinct syntax."

Comment: *"Why should RDBMS tags be any different?"* What tools you have at your disposal can actually change quite significantly with (R)DBMS products. Knowing what version the user is running is often vital as it means that we know what we can (or more importantly) *can't* use in our answers. Unlike programming languages, where updating to a new version is (normally) free, for (R)DBMS the licence fees are high for an upgrade; as such people will use versions that are 5, 10, or more years old sometimes, and lack *a lot* of functionality that recent versions "take for granted".

Answer (score 3):

These posts seem to be a bit "all over the place". There exists no FAQ as such (faq-proposal is for meta itself), but we have (at least) these two posts on meta:

[Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)
[Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

The OP of the former was likely not aware of the latter, so they made a new post. This shows why writing technical FAQ entries like this on meta is not a good idea - they get lost in the meta flood and there's no technical tags here.

What should be done:

- We'll need to enlist one or several [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) gold badge users to lead and do the actual work (I'm not eligible). A separate post with a proposed major update to SQL tag wiki needs to be posted on meta, in the form of a community wiki. Gold badgers will update SQL tag wiki once there is sufficient community consensus.
- Then with the above infrastructure in place, both threads should be merged into the [SQL tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and no place else, as they are tag usage guidance of technical, tag-specific nature.
- Everything about how to post a good question on SO in general needs to be removed, unfortunately. It is common that we see this popping up in specific posting guidance post, when users try to write extensive, detailed advice but get carried away. While it is good stuff, a tag usage/posting FAQ is not the right place for it.
- All the barf about "here are some misc database tags you can use" should probably be removed from the tag wiki. It isn't helpful and will be painful to maintain. It would be far more useful to have a list of available DBMS tags that should be used together with [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql).

Comment: I don't see a need for gold badgers to lead on this. Other people are perfectly capable of understanding the issues involved well enough to do it, and the gold badge doesn't grant any powers that are relevant here.

Comment: @MarkAmery Then you are assuming that the posts linked are technically correct and up to date. I wouldn't do that. Gold badge is the only way we have to tell that someone has relevant technical expertise. In addition, someone would have to review what's already in the SQL tag wiki. Etc. It's very easy for someone without deeper technical expertise to make incorrect assumptions. Formally you just need someone with 20k+ rep to update the wiki. But eh, given the traffic of the SQL tag, finding gold badge users should be easy.