# Custom post form for questions belonging to specific category

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm a seasoned question answerer on Stack Overflow and tend to be a generalist towards the sql tag, occasionally answer to the regex and python tags. Everyday I scroll the questions thread and see many posts that are in need of better formatting, miss expected output, sometimes data isn't shared at all, or is shared as images, other times description is missing, and many other common issues that do not conform to the [best practices to make a clear sql post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question).

These issues tend to come from people who registered on Stack Overflow for posting a question for their very first time, and they bump into that typical big blank form. Most of them, for their very SO newcomer nature, don't even know in advance anything about how to write a well-formatted question on this platform. This translates in having lots of unclear posts that require extra work for answerers and moderators to instruct always the same base SO guidelines to thousands of people. Sometimes those posts are never improved and get filled with comments related to good question standards, they follow up in low-quality lists first (or get flagged), then close lists, eventually deletion lists, and there's a lot of people cross-checking posts here and there.

The nature of my feature request is based on prevention rather than fixing. If we manage to help people with guides while they're writing their post, we can improve the overall quality of posts in advance.

This feature would involve to give depth to the question form, by splitting it in specific sections, each of which to exist/be filled based on:

- the tags related to the question they're asking (sql questions are different from C programming ones, and regex ones, because they require very different details to be presented)
- the kind of question their asking (more theoretical, data-related, debugging)

In the specific example of sql posts, the link I've shared before already provides an idea of sections that a sql post is expected to showcase. At the same time, the sections contained in that form would be different with respect to regex posts too, because they follow their own [regex guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222498/how-to-ask-a-good-regex-question). Even the Meta SO form I'm writing right now could be split in 'Situation', 'Problem', 'Comments' (a quick example, that can be refined for sure, just to give an idea).

This would be a very difficult feature to be implemented (due to the big variety of kind of questions and tags that can be found on Stack Overflow), although managing to have such sections-guidelines would not allow posters:

- to leave empty, required, highly-specific sections
- to have bad formatting for each section (e.g. a table can't be uploaded as an image)

and save thousands of hours spent everyday in advance to the big community of this platform.

To overcome the complexity implementation of such feature, could be useful to create custom forms for tags gradually, although enforcing the tag setting at the beginning of the post. If the specific main tag (for example SQL) falls into a custom form category, that form would appear in place of the big blank form.

Just an idea under my perspective, eager to learn about others' perspective on this one.

---

**How this differs from the Staging Ground proposal.**

The [Staging Ground proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416428/introducing-the-staging-ground-an-attempt-at-improving-the-first-time-asker-exp) differs from this proposal in two main ways:

- former attempts to provide "generic" guidelines for good question posting, while this one tries to be "highly specific" according to the main tag selected by the poster
- former requires "people spending time" to get involved to help newcomers, while this one wants to "avoid people getting involved", and reduce newcomers freedom of the big blank form into specifically described sections that help poster with a description of what the section should contain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Introducing the Staging Ground, an attempt at improving the first-time asker experience - What was asking your first question like?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416428/introducing-the-staging-ground-an-attempt-at-improving-the-first-time-asker-exp)

Comment: As a user that participated in the first trial much of what you want does seem to be addressed here. Yes, users may continue to initially create a question that doesn't meet the guidelines properly, but curators in the SG were able to address this *before* the question was posted (to the wider community) and use the comments to guide the user. If the user doesn't address those problems, the question doesn't get posted, and thus doesn't get answered. It's very much the asker's prerogative to get the question in a better place, and hopefully they'll learn from the experience.

Comment: Staging Ground would still involve people from SO to do that kind of job (which is currently more or less done in a public way with comments, revisions and flagging). My idea was to solve this problem through guides embedded in the question form directly, according to the main tag of the post (sql debugging posts feature specific sections, regex others, javascript would feature the presence of snippets, math ones will have dedicated section for formulas, etc..) and the kind of question (more theoretical? involves code debugging?).

Comment: All the information you talk about is there, just the users don't consume it. [[Tag:SQL]], for example, explicitly says to not use images, to provide DDL and DML, that fiddles can help but isn't a replacement for omitting it from the question, etc. Many other tags offer similar good guidance. Users just don't read it. Many don't even bother to read the tour or even note to very explicit notice in the question wizard that says to *not post images of code*.

Comment: It's not just about descriptions, it's also about customizing what you can (and what you can't) write in a specific section and ensuring that section does not go blank. If you don't allow images upload in a section that requires you to provide the expected output table, users won't be able to do that. The issue with low-quality posts is tightly related to the freedom users have with the big blank form.

Comment: You'd need some very clever logic then; what would stop a user posting nonsense in the required section? What stops the user just posting the image of data in a section that *does* allow images? How would this scale with new tags without development from the [so] team?

Comment: Your point about scalability is legit, that's why I called it "*a very difficult feature to be implemented*" (mentioning this post, before stating advantages of having such feature).